# Create file of an ArrayList of java class

Tags: java, android, file, arraylist

I'm making an Android app that reminds me when it's someone's birthday.

I'm now able to add a name and the corresponding date.
But, where I'm currently stuck at is the saving part. I've already tried looking up some solutions but was unable to port it to my needs. Since it's an ArrayList and not a simple String it cannot be Serialized (If I'm correct?) and therefore not be saved. So is there any other way to save this kind of data?

Here is my code:

Item.java:

```
public class Item implements Serializable{
  private String name;
  private String date;

  public Item(String name, String date){
      this.name = name;
      this.date = date;
  }

  public String getName(){
      return name;
  }

  public String getDate(){
      return date;
  }

  public void setName(String name){
      this.name = name;
  }

  public void setDate(String date){
      this.date = date;
  }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
static RecyclerviewAdapter adapter;

static ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

private static String nameText;
private static String birthString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(itemList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AddBirthday();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        month++;
        birthString = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
        itemList.add(new Item(nameText, birthString));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        saveArrayList(getContext(), itemList);
    }
}

private void AddBirthday() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Name");

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            nameText = input.getText().toString();

            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public static void saveArrayList(Context c, ArrayList<Item> arrayList) {

}  
}
```

Comment: Please show what saving options you have looked up and how they are unsuitable to your needs. Otherwise this sounds "too broad".

Comment: `ArrayList` is a serializable class.

Comment: I've tried doing it with Shared preferences but read that it wouldn't be efficient with that. Then I tried using a File output, but didn't really get how to use it with an ArrayList<Item>. Have I given enough information? I really wanna know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem serializing or deserializing ArrayLists in Java:

```
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new Item("A", "2006"));
    list.add(new Item("B", "2016"));


    // Serialize
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("list.ser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    os.writeObject(list);
    os.close();
    fos.close();


    // Deserialize

    FileInputStream fileIn = context.openFileInput("list.ser");
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    list = (List<Item>) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    fileIn.close();

    // Implement toString() in Item
    System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: But this is a list of Strings, I'm using a list of an object Item.java, so how I would be able to put that in a file is what I would like to know.

Comment: I edited my answer to demonstrate that it will work the same way. Try it.